# MySQL - updating column from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

Can't get this to work. I have a table 'Players' which has a primary key 'Id' and among others, a 'Name' column. Another table 'Bookings' has a column 'PlayerId' which references 'Players.Id'.

I have just added a column 'Name' to 'Bookings' which needs to contain an actual copy of the player's name.

I am trying set fill in all the names in Bookings using the following statement:

```
UPDATE Bookings SET Name = (SELECT Name FROM Players WHERE Players.Id=Bookings.PlayerId);
```

but what I get is error 1263: "Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'Name' at row 0".

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update Bookings, Players
set Bookings.Name = Players.Name
where Bookings.playerId = Players.Id
```

You have to be sure that there's a *one to one* relation between `Players` and `Bookings` (it's the only way I think this makes any sense).

Answer (score 1):

Use MYSQL UPDATE JOIN for this purpose. This is the query you need:

```
UPDATE Bookings
LEFT JOIN Players
ON Players.Id=Bookings.PlayerId
SET Bookings.Name = Players.Name
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, same error. Should have said that Bookings.PlayerId can be NULL. Tried adding WHERE Bookings.PlayerId<>NULL as the overall predicate - that got rid of the error but then no Name columns got set at all.